# Can multiple iOS apps on the same device connect to the same peripheral and not share the connection?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've read posts that say that multiple iOS apps on the same iPhone can connect to the same device.  But are they sharing one connection or does each app have its own connection?  If they are sharing a connection, isn't that a security problem for one app to see data for the second app?

More specifically, see the following conceptual diagram.  Is there a Connection 1 and a Connection 2 as diagramed even though the user would only see one connection in Bluetooth Settings?

Apple docs, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html), list the method to use in CBCentralManager to connect to a connected device (look at last paragraph).

If there is one connection, why would Apple allow this due to the security issues?

[image]

Comment: There is only one connection. There isn't a security issue since the granularity of the connection is device level, there is no concept of separating data at the app level.

Comment: Can you please explain further. If Device A emits heart rate data to app 1 in the background, does App 2 get access to that data if it choses to listen to all data coming from Device A?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Both app 1 and app 2 were installed by the device owner, so they are both equally trusted to access peripheral data

Comment: Do you have a pointer to some documentation on this?  Thanks for the help.